# How to subscribe to .ics url in Evolution calendar?

Tags: evolution, calendar

I have a remote url that delivers an up-to-date `.ics` or iCalendar file, I want to know how to subscribe in Evolution's calendar

Answer (score 4):

open Evolution, go to the calendar

New [dropdown to] Calendar

Type: On The Web

put in your URL, maybe your username. my calendar didn't require credentials to access, so this worked perfectly

Comment: My remote url started with `webcal://` in case people are curious. This answer works.